# Django Form Field missing on save

Tags: python, django

I have a user facing form, which is generated from a model. The model has a foreign key to a site “Section.” When I submit the form it returns an IntegrityError (null value in column "section_id" violates not-null constraint). I thought the issue was straightforward until I started working on it. The bug only occurs on my development server (CentOS release 5.5 (Final)). I don’t have this issue on my local environment (Mac OS X 10.5.8).

I entered the python shell and examined the form object; I noticed the “section” field (form.fields.section) was missing on my dev env. Both the project code and django version are identical on my local and dev. Adding to my frustration is the fact that the user facing form does have a hidden “section” field, but when that data is posted to the view the form field no longer exists. Any insight into the cause of this bug would be greatly appreciated and save me from the expense of Rogaine.

Thanks in advance,
Chris.

Code:

views.py

```
def event_registration(request, slug):
    section = get_object_or_404(Section, section__slug=slug)
    parent_page = Page.objects.get(section=section, slug='overview')
    page = Page.objects.get(section=section, slug='events-registration')

    form = EventRegistrationForm(label_suffix='')
    submitted = False

    if request.POST.has_key('event'):
        form = EventRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            submitted = True

    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('section/event_registration.html',
                            {
                                'section': section,
                                'page': page,
                                'form': form,
                                'submitted': submitted
                            },
                            context_instance=context)
```

forms.py

```
class EventRegistrationForm(better_forms.BetterModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EventRegistration
        fieldsets = [
                        ('Step 1', {
                            'fields': ['event', 'guests']
                        }),
                        ('Step 2', {
                            'fields': ['first_name', 'email', 'last_name', 'phone', 'school_name']
                        }),
                    ]
```

models.py

```
class EventRegistration(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Theater, verbose_name=_('Section'), 
        help_text=_("The Site Section"))
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_('Event'))
    guests = models.IntegerField(_('Number of Guests?'))
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(_('E-Mail Address'), max_length=255)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(_('Daytime Phone Number'))
    school_name = models.CharField(_('School Name'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: post some code. i.e. forms.py, views.py, models.py

Comment: can you post your entire view? you aren't setting an instance to your form so there would be no section value when you try to save. If you post more of your view i may be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Okay, I have the entire view.

Comment: @ Kenzic posted an answer, but headed to a lab meeting. Will check back in a couple hours and will elaborate or clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your view:

```
def event_registration(request, slug):
    section = get_object_or_404(Section, section__slug=slug)
    parent_page = Page.objects.get(section=section, slug='overview')
    page = Page.objects.get(section=section, slug='events-registration')

    eventr = EventRegistration(section=section)
    submitted = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventRegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=eventr)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            submitted = True
    else:
        form = EventRegistrationForm(label_suffix='', instance=eventr)

    context = {
                 'section': section,
                 'page': page,
                 'form': form,
                 'submitted': submitted
              }
    return render_to_response('section/event_registration.html', context,
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

edit:

technically, if you had just changed

```
form.save()
to
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.section=section
instance.save()
```

that would have also worked. You needed to fill out the section field of the new EventRegistration before committing it to the db.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Do you know why my code worked on my local?

Comment: This is a guess... but your local database probably didn't have section not null constraint

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

This sounds like an issue of your database's not being the same version. Did you sync your databases are separate times or are you using different databases on your development server and local machine? Can you also post the full model and form as an example?

Comment: it doesn't seem like his database isn't synced. He is getting a db integrity error because his form is not passing a value to his section fk so it is trying to save a null to a not null constrained db column.

Comment: The databases appears to be synced up.